# How to connect Vue.js as frontend and FastAPI as backend?

Tags: vue.js, fastapi

I'm building a project On Jobs Portal and I need Vue as frontend and FastAPI as backend for add, delete, update. I want to know if I can connect these both or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> #### I want to know if i can connect these both or not.

### Quick answer: Yes, you can connect.

But there are many ways, you can render templates with something like Jinja or you can create a completely different project with something like Vue CLI and you might want to use something like Nginx or Apache etc to connect both.

So let's create an example app with Jinja

### Structure

```py
├── main.py
└── templates
    └── home.html
```

### Backend- `main.py`

- We are serving our frontend in `/` and rendering our `home.html` in that path.
- We are using the templates folder to keep our HTML's and passing it to Jinja.
- Also, we are going to send a request to `/add` from our front-end.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates") 

app = FastAPI()


class TextArea(BaseModel):
    content: str


@app.post("/add")
async def post_textarea(data: TextArea):
    print(data.dict())
    return {**data.dict()}


@app.get("/")
async def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request})
```

### Frontend - `home.html`

- Let us create a dummy app that has a textarea and button.
- We are using Axios to send our requests to backend.
- Since they are running on the same port we can pass `/add` to Axios directly.

```js
<html>
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <textarea name="" id="content" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="content"></textarea>
        <button @click="addText" id="add-textarea">click me</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                title: '',
                content: ''
            },
            methods: {
                addText() {
                    return axios.post("/add", {
                        content: this.content
                    }, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        }
                    }).then((response) => {
                        console.log("content: " + this.content);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the end, you will have a terrible looking textarea and a button. But it will help you to understand things better.

[image]

```py
 {'content': 'Hello textarea!'}
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51682 - "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: what if i'm using file.vue instead of file.html?

Comment: Jinja is an HTML rendering framework, thats exactly what I meant by if you want to use components you will need to run frontend and backend independently and you need to merge them with something like Nginx Apache etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it, in quite a clean way IMO.
The best I can come up with is using Node.js/npm to bundle the Vue app to a `dist/` folder (by default)

```
vue-cli-service build
```

I then use the project folder structure like this

```
├── dist/ <- Vue-CLI output
    └── index.html
├── src/ <- Vue source files
└── app.py
```

To archieve the same project setup, you can just simply init a Vue project using `vue create` and create your Python project in a same folder (using a IDE like Pycharm for example, make sure you don't override one with the other).

Then you can use `FastAPI.staticfiles.StaticFiles` to serve them

```py
# app.py

app.mount('/', StaticFiles(directory='dist', html=True))
```

Remember to put the above `app.mount()` line after all other routes though, since it will override every route that comes after.

You can even use `vue-cli-service build --watch` so that every change in Vue code will be reflected in the HTML file right after, and all you need to do is to press F5 on your browser to see those changes.

You can change the `dist` folder output to something else too, using `vue-cli-service build --dest=<folder name>` and change `directory` parameter in `app.mount()` line above. (according to [Vue-CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build))

Here is one of my projects using that setup: https://github.com/KhanhhNe/sshmanager-v2

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions for using Vue for the entire frontend you can go modify the `vue.config.js` file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,    //Transpile your dependencies
  publicPath: "/static",          //Path of static directory
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),   // Output path for the static files
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  devServer: {
    // Write files to disk in dev mode, so FastAPI can serve the assets
    port: 8080,
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    }
  },
})
```

Then in the vue-cli you can run either build or serve (this is in the task page) or in the console run

```
npm run build
```

This will transpile your staticfiles to the output folder you set on in the `vue.config.js` file. Next are two options with and without jinja2

**Without Jinja**

Next go to `main.py` on Fastapi and add the two lines below

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles   #<-- Add this

app = FastAPI()


#static files & load
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static", html = True), name="static") #<-- Add this
```

There should be a `index.html` page in the static folder the line with the `app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static", html = True), name="static")` sets the directory for the path to the static file and loads the html file to "/".

You can add, delete, update, and query using a GraphQL library

**With jinja2**

Go to `main.py` on Fastapi and add the two lines below

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates 
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles   

app = FastAPI()


#static files & load
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static", html = True), name="static") 
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="static")

@app.get("/")
async def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Here the `index.html` page that is transpiled is loaded in as a jinja template. You can write your GET and POST functions on the `main.js`